# How to change my $first date aggregation to be MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is the updated version after the answer i have received. I tried to run this but instead of giving  me the correct output, it just says that the record is not found. I think it is some issues with the brackets but i have looked through the whole thing but failed to see the issue.

```
db.contact.aggregate([
         { $sort: { machine_Id: 1, date: 1 } },
         {
           $group:
             {
               _id: "$machine_Id",
               firstDate: { $first: "$date" }
             }
         },
       {
          $project:{
             date:{
                $split:[
                   "$firstDate",
                   "/"
                ]
             }
          }
       },
       {
          $project:{
             date:{
                $concat:[
                   {
                      $arrayElemAt:[
                         "$date",
                         1
                      ]
                   },
                   "/",
                   {
                      $arrayElemAt:[
                         "$date",
                         0
                      ]
                   },
                   "/",
                   {
                      $arrayElemAt:[
                         "$date",
                         2
                      ]
                   }
                ]
             }
          }
       }
    ] ,function(err, meibanlist) {
      if( err || !meibanlist ) console.log("Record not found");
      else meibanlist.forEach (function(machine_Id){
        console.log(machine_Id);
      });
    });
```

Comment: use $dateToString: add a $project stage at the end of your query: { $project: { time: { $dateToString: { format: "%d/%m/%Y", date: "$firstDate" } } }}

Comment: @felix `$dateToString` will only work for date types; in the above case, the dates are already of string type, so that won't work. The OP needs to first convert the `date` field to a proper date type and then apply the `$dateToString` operator.

Comment: @chridam you're right. I've add a solution to avoid converting the string field to ISODate, see the answer below

Comment: i tried to use the codes below but it doesnt work. It shows me the output record not found' though